# I must go now. vs. I must be off now

Tags: phrase-usage, idiomatic-language

> I must go now.

> I must be off now.

Is there any nuance between the two sentences?

Comment: For what it's worth, they both sound a bit British to my American ears, but that's no reason not to use them in America.

Comment: I would say "I have to go now" in almost all cases, except for when it would be appropriate to use the informal "I've gotta go."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first uses the plain verb "go".  Using plain and simple language is typical of rather formal speech.  You could also say "I must leave now." It is rather formal.

The second uses an idiom, "to be off". The use of idioms is more casual or colloquial, and more typical of spoken English.

Comment: TBH, as an American, having lived East coast, Intermountain West, and the Midwest, "I must go now" feels fairly formal, too. "I've gotta go now" would be far more common. Overall, +1, though.

Comment: "It's time for me to go" is the most natural equivalent of "I must be off now" to my US ears.  "I've gotta go" would suggest to me that the speaker needed a bathroom.

Answer (score 1):

They mean the same.

The first sounds awkward and formal, it's like something Spock from Star Trek would say.

The second sounds British.

More ways of saying the same thing:

I have to go now.

I gotta go now.